# c# OData V4, EntityFramework 6, missing properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, odata, edmx

I am trying to migrate a service working fine on oData V3 to V4.
I am using EntityFramework 6 to generate the code from my database. This is the code generated :

```
   namespace MyEntities
{
    using System;

    public partial class Civilite
    {

        public System.Guid pkCivilite { get; set; }
        public string civilite { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is my WebApiConfig :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services


            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataModelBuilder();

            builder.Namespace = "DataService";
            builder.ContainerName = "Container";

            var civiliteSet = builder.EntitySet<MyEntities.Civilite>("Civilites");
            civiliteSet.EntityType.HasKey(entity => entity.pkCivilite);

            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "odata",
            routePrefix: null,
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());

            config.EnsureInitialized();


        }

    }
```

This is my controller :

```
public class CivilitesController : ODataController
    {

        MyEntities.Container db = new MyEntities.Container();

        private bool CiviliteExists(Guid key)
        {
            return db.CiviliteSet.Any(c => c.pkCivilite == key);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<MyEntities.Civilite> Get()
        {

            return db.CiviliteSet;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<MyEntities.Civilite> Get([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            IQueryable<MyEntities.Civilite> result = db.CiviliteSet.Where(p => p.pkCivilite == key);
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(MyEntities.Civilite civilite)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            db.CiviliteSet.Add(civilite);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Created(civilite);
        }
```

But the metadata does not return the property "civilite" of type string. It's only returning the primary key "pkCivilite" of type Guid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
<edmx:DataServices>
<Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="DataService">
<EntityType Name="Civilite">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="pkCivilite"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="pkCivilite" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Guid"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityContainer Name="Container">
<EntitySet Name="Civilites" EntityType="DataService.Civilite"/>
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

I tried to put [DataMember] on the property "civilite" without success.
The client request work. I get all the records but only with the "pkCivilite" property.
What am I doing wrong ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was to use `ODataModelBuilder` instead of `ODataConventionModelBuilder`.

So I needed to write:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
```